# Nedd help understanding why only a JOIN with a subquery returns the correct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m quite new to SQL and need help in order to understand why the values vary so much. I guess the JOIN concept isn´t quite clear to me yet.

I have two tables:
table games (id, account_id, game_date, game_id)
 table reports (id, offender_id, reported_date, comment)

I want to get all the acounts that were reported, their total games played and the % on which they were reported

I could manage to get the correct answer. Just need help on understanding why the Second query works and the first one returns the incorrect value

First query:

```
SELECT
    j.account_id,
    COUNT(j.account_id) AS Total_Games_Played,     
    COUNT(r.offender_id) AS Total_Reports, 
    COUNT(j.account_id) AS Total_Games, 
    COUNT(r.offender_id)/ COUNT(j.account_id) AS PCG_Games_Reporte
FROM jogos j 
JOIN reports r 
    ON j.account_id = r.offender_id
GROUP BY j.account_id
ORDER BY Total_Games_Played DESC ;
```

Second query

```
SELECT 
    g.account_id, 
    r.Total_Reported, 
    COUNT(g.account_id) AS Total_Games,                     
    r.Total_Reported/ COUNT(g.account_id) AS PCG_Games_Reported
FROM games g 
JOIN (
        SELECT
            offender_id,
            COUNT(offender_id) AS Total_Reported 
        FROM reports
        GROUP BY offender_id
    ) r 
    ON g.account_id = r.offender_id
GROUP BY g.account_id
ORDER BY Total_Reported DESC ;
```

Link for both outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E3fB.jpg

Comment: The first one I forgot to change the table name to (games g) because I was using the names in my native language. srry

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have one to many relationship between `reports` and `games`. So if you count after the `Join` the records will be duplicated and the duplicated records will be counted.

But in the second query you are counting the `offender_id` first in the `reports` table and joining the result which will avoid duplicates unlike the first query

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `COUNT(<col>)` simply counts the number of non-NULL values in the column.  Because `j.account_id` and `r.offender_id` are -- presumably -- not `NULL`, you get the same count.  You will understand this better if you run the query without the `GROUP BY` (`SELECT *` is fine) to see what results the `JOIN` produces.

You can do what you want using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  I think this is the logic:

```
SELECT j.account_id, COUNT(j.account_id) AS Total_Games_Played, 
       COUNT(r.offender_id) AS Total_Reports,
       COUNT(DISTINCT j.account_id) AS Total_Games,
       COUNT(r.offender_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT j.account_id) AS PCG_Games_Reporte
FROM jogos j JOIN
     reports r 
     ON j.account_id = r.offender_id
GROUP BY j.account_id
ORDER BY Total_Games_Played DESC ;
```

I might have the `DISTINCT` in the wrong place (it can be hard to set up query logic without sample data).

Comment: The query still returns duplicate values. THe data is a litte bit confusing as well , sorry.

Every account_id entry represents a different game. The primary key is 'id', so if I count every account_id entry it should return the total games played